# Handling iOS device rotation programmatically

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, screen-rotation

I'm working on my app that is based on a navigationController, all programatically, no XIBs. Before, when I used XIBs, I would set `springs & struts.` [like so](http://cupsofcocoa.com/)

But now my app is all programmatically done, so, how can I manage the rotations? Is there any tutorial with this?

Do I have to create two different view controllers for each view? Or according to orientation in the same view controller show the UI elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The springs and struts in a nib control the [`autoresizingMask` property of the `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6).  You can set them programatically.  This is explained further in the [“Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Resizing Rules” section of the *View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5).

Comment: actually after browsing through that makes me wonder if a handled a recent situation the proper manner.  On rotation several objects displayed in the correct coordinates.  So I added the CGRectMake statements to the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method.  Do you think this method is acceptable also?

Comment: No.  If you need to set your view frames manually, you should do it in the view controller's `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method or in the view's `layoutSubviews` method.